# Display of image in GEE (Sentinel-2) does not display the masked values using SCL band

Tags: google-earth-engine

The code below aimed (aims) to add the images of a Sentinel-2 Collection (S2_SR), after performing the addition of a NDVI band per image, and a cloud masking using the Scene Classification Layer which comes to L2A product of Sentinel-2 Imagery.

```
var cld = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:cloud_masks')


// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// Select AOI 
// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Map.addLayer(region)


// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// Finding images in the Sentinel2 L2A Collection 
// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
  .filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE', 'equals', '32UQC')
  .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30));


  // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// Printing the number of images in the request 
// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
print(s2.size())


// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// Function to display the images Sentinel-2 in False Color composite 
// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
function addImage(image) { // display each image in collection

  var id = image.id
  var image = ee.Image(image.id)
  var array = id.split("/");
  var date = array[2];
  var date = date.slice(0, 8);
  print(image)

  Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['B8', 'B11', 'B4'], max: 5000}, date)
}

/*
s2.evaluate(function(s2){
  s2.features.map(addImage)
})
*/


// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// Function to mask cloud from built-in Scene Classification Layer band 
// in Level2A Sentinel-2 imagery 
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
function maskcloud(image){
    var masked = cld.sclMask(['cloud_low', 'cloud_medium', 'cloud_high', 'shadow', 'snow','cirrus'])(image)
    return masked
  }


// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// Function to calculate and add an NDVI band
// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
var addNDVI = function(image) {
    return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']));
    };


// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// Add NDVI band to image collection
// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
var S2 = s2.map(maskcloud)
.map(addNDVI);


// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
// Extract NDVI band and create NDVI median composite image
// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
var NDVI = S2.select(['nd']);
var NDVI = NDVI.median();

// PRINTING WHAT S2 and s2 mean _Data_Type__
print(s2)
print("-------------------'")
print(S2)


print("------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("               ADDING IMAGERY WITH DISPLAY FUNCTION              ")
print("------------------------------------------------------------------------")

// Mapping the collection with the addImage function 

/*
S2.evaluate(function(S2) {  // use map on client-side
    S2.features.map(addImage)
    }
)
*/

Map.addLayer(S2.first(), {bands:['B8', 'B11', 'B4'], min:0, max:5000}, 'S2 masked image')
```

When I execute the code, The first image of the feature collection S2 is displayed, with masked out values determine for the classes I wanted out of the SCL. However if I activate the code block:

```
/*
S2.evaluate(function(S2) {  // use map on client-side
    S2.features.map(addImage)
    }
)
*/
```

Images are added to my Map, but they does not display the masked values as in:

```
Map.addLayer(S2.first(), {bands:['B8', 'B11', 'B4'], min:0, max:5000}, 'S2 masked image')
```

My question 
Does .map() does not work when Applied to the Feature Collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your `S2` collection to perform masking, but your `addImage` function does not refer to `S2` at all; it is fetching unaltered images from Earth Engine (via `ee.Image(...)`) that happen to have the same IDs.

Here is a replacement which does retrieve the images from `S2`:

```
function addImage(clientSideImage) {
  var idInCollection = clientSideImage.properties['system:index'];
  var serverSideImage = S2.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', idInCollection)).first();
  Map.addLayer(serverSideImage, {bands: ['B8', 'B11', 'B4'], max: 5000}, date);
}
```

Of course, this now makes the `addImage` function specific to `S2`. If you want to use it in general, you will need to pass in the collection as a parameter:

```
function addImage(collection, clientSideImage) {
  var idInCollection = clientSideImage.properties['system:index'];
  var date = idInCollection.slice(0, 8);
  var serverSideImage = collection.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', idInCollection)).first();
  Map.addLayer(serverSideImage, {bands: ['B8', 'B11', 'B4'], max: 5000}, date);
}
```

This version of `addImage` requires the collection as another parameter, so you'll need to provide it:

```
S2.evaluate(function(clientSideS2) {
  clientSideS2.features.forEach(function(clientSideImage) {
    addImage(S2, clientSideImage);
  });
});
```

(I have replaced `map` with `forEach` because in JS, `map` builds a result list which isn't being used; `forEach` calls the function but doesn't build a list. But either one would work the same here; this is just for tidiness.)

---

By the way, I recommend that you practice giving variables more meaningful names (e.g. perhaps `maskedS2` instead of distinguishing `S2` from `s2`), and avoiding reusing variable names (in your original call to `addImage`, you're shadowing the server-side `S2` with a client-side version — which I had to rename to make the revised version possible, and in `addImage` the variable `image` is both a client-side and a server-side value).

This has a number of benefits: more descriptive names help others understand your code (and when you're asking for help, that can make the difference between getting an answer and not getting one); typos are less likely to get the wrong answer rather than an error; and in particular, avoiding reusing variables allows you to more freely reorganize your code because the same name always means the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and help. I have a question though. In this function, which is for a more general usage and not *hard coded* for S2 collection. ```function addImage(collection, clientSideImage) {
  var idInCollection = clientSideImage.properties['system:index'];
  var date = idInCollection.slice(0, 8);
  var serverSideImage = S2.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', idInCollection)).first();
  Map.addLayer(serverSideImage, {bands: ['B8', 'B11', 'B4'], max: 5000}, date);
}``` you put the variable S2 to filter per index, however should it not be collection.filter?

Comment: @almrog You are correct, and I have edited to fix that. Sorry, I was undoing changes to my copy of the code to write the final version of my answer, and missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! The clarification was very useful. I applied to my script and now works!